# Lubuntu 13.04: Can't find Catfish in the menu

Tags: lubuntu, search, thunar, location

I don't seem to have any earch options in Thunar. So I went to the Software Center and searched for Catfish. I found it and says its already installed! The softeware center says I must look in menu->Accesories->Catfish File Search, but it's not there. What can I do? How do I find it and integrate it in Thunar?

Comment: Lubuntu doesn't have Thunar, it has PCManFM. Are you using a default Lubuntu or have you added/removed software? According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/lubuntu-desktop, `Catfish` isn't present by default in Lubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Does it work if you run `catfish` in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reinstall it? So open terminal and try:

> sudo apt-get remove catfish
>
> sudo apt-get install catfish